# Does a physical barrier such as Vaseline help prevent a cold or flu during air-travel?

Tags: medical-science, common-cold

[This site claims](https://www.caring.com/articles/7-ways-to-avoid-getting-sick-when-you-fly) that this action will *help* prevent you getting sick during air-travel:

> try applying a small amount of Neosporin or petroleum jelly just inside the nostrils (use a Q-tip if your hands aren't freshly washed).Experts say the antibacterial action of Neosporin is unlikely to present much of a barrier when used in this way, but it never hurts to moisturize the inside of the nose

Is there any validity to this claim?

Related: [Can triple antibiotic ointment in the nostrils prevent flu?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26786/can-triple-antibiotic-ointment-in-the-nostrils-prevent-flu)

Comment: Which claim: antibacterial or moist?

Comment: My question was specifically about the physical barrier preventing illness (especially _viral_ illnesses).